# When save in mysql I get numeric value for string value in case switch php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save a value from case switch in php, but when save it in mysql I get a numeric value and Not a string value. When run this and do a echo a var, I can see  perfect value for example NE,NNE,ENE but when I tried save it in mysql in string field, the value that I get are  numeric in my database mysql, for example 3.533, 9,876.

```
function getCompassDirection($bearing) {
     $tmp = round($bearing / 22.5);
     switch($tmp) {
          case 1:
               $direction = "NNE";
               break;
          case 2:
               $direction = "NE";
               break;
          case 3:
               $direction = "ENE";
               break;
          case 4:
               $direction = "E";
               break;
          case 5:
               .
               .
          case 15:
               $direction = "NNW";
               break;
          default:
               $direction = "N";
     }
     $GLOBALS['bearing'] = $direction;

}
```

My query to save the data in mysql

```
$bearing=$GLOBALS['bearing'];
$sql = "insert into paradas(id_user,id_dispositivo, bearing) values('$id_user','$id_dispositivo','$bearing')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
```

Apreciate your help.

Comment: That SQL statement looks invalid - `VALUE VALUES`?

Comment: plus, there was a comment (now deleted) that asked about what your column type was (and length) I added that.

Comment: @user4131013 - `var_dump($GLOBALS['bearing'])` at the end of your function. Do the same before you generate your SQL. Also, you're suppressing errors with that `@`, and you don't want to do that, at least in development; you also want to check the return value of `mysql_query` to see if the query succeeds. Finally - look at switching to `mysqli_` or `PDO`, as `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: seems like I too have fallen onto deaf ears @andrewsi - *walking away...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the columns from (int) to (VARCHAR) in the MySQL table structure. Happens all the time.